# Is it possible to inherit an interface from multiple other interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi  angular community,

Is it possible to include three interfaces nested inside another, think my code will explain it more than my sentence:
 I am trying to implement the interface IProject1 & IProject2 & IProject3 to be part of the IAdmin2 interface:

Thanks in advance

```
 import {IBusiness} from "./business";
 import {ITechnology} from "./technology";
 export interface IAdmin2 {
     id: number;
     business_id: number;
     technology_ids: number[];
     trigram: string;
     position: string;
     years_experience: number;
     notification: boolean;
     availability: any;
     form_admin2_file: File;
     business: IBusiness;
     technologies: ITechnology[];
     admin2Translations: any;
     translations: any;
    delete: any;
    data: any;
  ** Include interface Iproject1**
  ** Include interface Iproject2**
  ** Include interface Iproject3**
 }


 import {ITechnology} from "./technology";
 import {IProjectFile} from "./project-file";
 export interface IProject1 {
     id: number;
    name: string;
    start_date: any;
    technologies: ITechnology[];
    description: string;
    sector_id: number;
    end_date: any;
    team_size: number;
}

 import {ITechnology} from "./technology";
 import {IProjectFile} from "./project-file";
 export interface IProject2 {
     id: number;
    name: string;
    start_date: any;
    technologies: ITechnology[];
    description: string;
    sector_id: number;
    end_date: any;
    team_size: number;
}

 import {ITechnology} from "./technology";
 import {IProjectFile} from "./project-file";
 export interface IProject3 {
     id: number;
    name: string;
    start_date: any;
    technologies: ITechnology[];
    description: string;
    sector_id: number;
    end_date: any;
    team_size: number;
}
```

Comment: Actiually, your cond doesn't explain it as well as text could. What do you want to do? Inherit from an interface? Then use `extends`. Or something else? Then you have to explain what you mean.

Comment: @Sefe ues thats it, inherit from interfaces (3 in fact), I need to include 3 interfaces in one (maybe should I update my post..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TypeScript you can inherit an interface from one or more base interfaces:

```
interface IProject1 {
}

interface IProject2 {
}

interface IProject3 {
}

interface IAdmin2 extends IProject1, IProject2, IProject3 {
}
```

As a result, implementations of `IAdmin2` will also have to implement `IProject1`, `IProject2` and `IProject3`. You can also check [the official documentation of interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Comment: thanks I updated my post, so it is possible to extend three interfaces according to your exemple bellow?

Comment: greeeeaaaaaat :-)